# How to integrate esb for multiplt REST applications

Tags: wso2-esb

I am very new to wso2esb, i need to design the esb service which iteract with the multiple REST application e.g Ruby on Rails application. Please help me how i can achieve that. Please give me step by step information i am very new to it

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, here's how to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find information

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service

Comment: Thank you @alber arce. This article has helped me. I have achieved how we can access our REST api's using wso2esb. Can you help me how can I achieve the following scenario.
Sceanario: I want to access the REST api of app1 and want to send the response of app1 REST api to the REST api of app2. 
Thanks in advance.